# How do I get the permutation matrix of an element in the symmetric group?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a permutation in $S_4$, `Cycles[{2, 4}]`.  I want to produce the permutation matrix of this permutation.  In other words, I want Mathematica to return the list `{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}}`.

Comment: This seem the Identy Matrix with the rows 2 and 4 interchanged. `Table[IdentityMatrix[4][[i]],{i,PermutationList[Cycles[{{2, 4}}], 4]}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
n = 4
SparseArray[
 Transpose[{Range[n], PermutationList[Cycles[{{2, 4}}], n]}] -> 1,
 {n, n}
 ]
```

Comment: You don't even need to define `n` if you do `SparseArray@MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} -> 1 &, PermutationList[Cycles[{{2, 4}}]]]`.

Comment: I know. Btw., calling `SparseArray ` and `PermutationList` without a second argument is asking for trouble. And `Map` and friends are slow. ;)

Answer (score 8):

`IdentityMatrix[4][[#]]&/@PermutationList[Cycles[{{2, 4}}], 4]`

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.

Comment: `IdentityMatrix[4][[PermutationList[Cycles[{{2, 4}}], 4]]]` is a bit simpler.

Comment: also: `Permute[IdentityMatrix[4], Cycles[{{2, 4}}]]` (+1)

Answer (score 7):

Starting in version 13.1, one can just evaluate

```
PermutationMatrix[Cycles[{{2, 4}}]] // Normal
   {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

but it might be better to omit the `Normal[]` and keep the matrix in its structured form, since internal operations like `Dot[]` are optimized to work with the structured form.